# Check if array contains values of another array in the same order

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, the first being:

```
[4, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1]
```

and the second being:

```
[2, 7, 5]
```

How can I determine if the first array contains the *SAME* values (**and in the *SAME* order**) of the second array. In this case the function would return `TRUE` because the sequence `2, 7, 5` in fact is present in the first array. It would return `FALSE` for `2, 5, 7`. The values exist in the first array, but not in that exact order.

Is there an existing PHP function for this? If no, how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For common case of array contents:

```
$ar1 = [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 7, 5, 1,];
$ar2 = [2, 7, 5];

// Find point where sub-array can start
$keys = array_keys($ar1, $ar2[0]); 
foreach($keys as $k) 
   // Check that sub-array is the same as the second array 
   if(array_slice($ar1, $k, count($ar2)) == $ar2) 
       { echo "Wow!"; break; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you array is just numbers, i would suggest a trick:

```
$a1 = [4, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1];
$a2 = [2, 7, 5];
// convert both arrays to strings, 
// add `,` in the beginning and end, see @splash58 comment
$a1_str = ',' . implode(',', $a1) . ',';
$a2_str = ',' . implode(',', $a2) . ',';
// check with strpos:
echo strpos($a1_str, $a2_str) !== false? 'Eq' : 'Not eq';
```

Comment: I can understand that this works, but isn't there a better way to achieve this? As converting the arrays to strings doesn't look quite right...

Comment: @u_mulder Wrap both strings with commas to avoid comparing 2,7,5 with 22,7,55. +1 because I thought the same way